# including php file using ajax, javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have one page first.php consisting of 2 division namely div1 and div2(which is empty at first).

When clicked on div1 it fires up the ajax request to process.php page which contains code which decide which file to include. if the decided file is file1.php which contains html codes like `<div class="box"></div>` then

my question is how can i include that file1.php within div2 without reloading the page first.php?

Code:

```
function bringData(data)
{

var request;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
request=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    request=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
request.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if(request.readyState==4 && request.status==200)
    {
        console.log("successfully COmpleted");
        console.log(request.responseText);
        document.getElementByClassName("space_area").innerHTML=request.responseText;
    }
}
request.open("POST","file1.php?p="+data,true);
request.send();


}
```

My file1.php file contains some ajax code which should executes at certain interval and brings data from database and change the color of box. On console i can see those ajax codes too . How can i make sure that those code performs their respective functions and only the output box is shown in div2?

Comment: Provide relevant code please, and show what you've tried.

Comment: You're already sending out an AJAX request to `process.php`. You can just include the contents of `file1.php` in the response.

Comment: Are you using jQuery, just javascript?

Answer (score 0):

use jquery.

```
$("div.div1").click(function(){
    $.ajax("file1.php").done(function(data){
        $("div.box").html=data;
    });
});
```

so, when you click on the div1 box, it'll call using ajax the URL "file1.php" and once loaded, it'll throw the stuff into the div with the id 'box'.

see:  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/  and http://api.jquery.com/click/  for details!

of course, you throw the script in  tags and maybe you'll need to put it in a $(document).ready(function(){...}); thing if you have dynamic content.

Comment: Thank you ! But how can i include this using purely javascript?

Comment: doing it with just javascript would be rather difficult.  just include the jquery script.  it'll save you a lot of time and effort.  see: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/ for details on howw jquery works.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you cannot include PHP scripts via JavaScript since PHP is executed by the server and JavaScript by the client but you can include and "combine" the OUTPUT of single php files via JavaScript using AJAX (I guess that is what you just mean).

With Ajax you can load the contents of another webpage (for example div2.php) and do with it whatever you want. So for example you can load your div.php file and place it somewhere in your code. You can find a pretty good tutorial for that on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp). But the code will become more "handsome" if you use [JQuerys Ajax functions](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).